# Как сделать, чтобы правильно отображалась форма user_form и profile_form?

Tags: python, django

Я реализовал в своем проекте регистрацию/авторизацию при помощи модуля django-allauth. Все данные о зарегистрированных пользователях хранятся в таблице auth_user. Помимо имени и фамилии пользователя мне бы хотелось в эту таблицу  добавить еще несколько дополнительных столбцов в которых хранилась бы разная информация о пользователе (дата рождения, биография, аватарка и т.д.). Прочитав одну статью на Хабре "Стратегии расширения Django User Model", я решил создать  дополнительную модель (модель я назвал profile) Django со своей таблицей в базе данных, которая бы связывала пользователя стандартной модели через связь OneToOneField. Я сделал все, как было сказано в статье. Все хорошо работает. Но проблема заключается в том, что на странице профиля не корректно отображается форма, которая должна менять значения в таблице profile (На случай если пользователь захочет поменять свои данные). Отображается только кнопка submit без input(s).

[image: profile_page.html]

[image: devTool]

Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы правильно отображалась форма user_form и profile_form?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django import forms
# from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = ['bio', 'birth_date', ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from .forms import UserForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import transaction

@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

profile_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles%}
{# block head#}
{% block title %}Профиль пользователя{% endblock %}

{#block body#}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Username: {{ user.username }}</li>
          <li>last_name: {{ user.last_name }}</li>
          <li>first_name: {{ user.first_name }}</li>
          <li>Biography: {{ user.profile.bio }}</li>
          <li>Birth Date: {{ user.profile.birth_date }}</li>
        </ul>
        <form method="POST" action="" style="border: solid 1px black">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ user_form.as_p }}
          {{ profile_form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        Вы не вошли в систему
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: С первого взгляда вроде все правильно. А что отладчика на вьюхе показывает? Поставьте Breakpoint на return и посмотрите, что передаётся в контекст

Comment: Кстати если формы не отображаются после post-запроса, вероятно у вас выполнение попадает, на `messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error bellow')) `. Но лучше глянуть через отладчика...

Comment: @Александр спасибо за помощь. Оказывается проблема была в том, что я неправильно указал path в urls.py. Правда, конечно, возникли другие проблемы, но и с ними я тоже разобрался =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Я неправильно указал path в urls.py. После этого форма стала отображаться как надо. Но при отправление формы возникла ошибка отправки.

Чтобы устранить ошибку В views.py надо заменить импорт `from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages` на импорт `from django.contrib import messages`.

Вместо  строки `messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))` поставьте строку `messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))`
Точно также в строке с messages.error уберите нижнее подчеркивание.

Ну и в редиректе я поставил другой путь. Т.е. при успешном отправление формы приложение переходит на главную страницу `redirect('/')`